# Find a combination of multiple vectors to fill a bigger vector element-wisely in R (according to their indexes)

Tags: r, list, vector, combinations, fill

Any hints for this task will be very appreciated.

There are repeated sequences in the original vectors from my interest, so I used the `rle function`, plus some additional management, to get a vector of indexes that correspond to the values of my interest in the original ones.

I did a simple simulation to better explain my purpose. Let's suppose I am interested in the repeated pattern/label "1" in vectors of length 20. For example:

```
vec_list <- list (
vec1 = c(2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,1),
vec2 = c(3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2),
vec3 = c(2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3) )
```

When I get the indexes of the repeated values equals 1, I get:

```
# for replication
indexes <- list(
vec1.a = 2:4, vec1.b = 10:12, vec1.c = 17:20,
vec2.a = 8:10, vec2.b = 18:19,
vec3.a = 4:6, vec3.b =11:15 )
```

resulting in the list:

```
indexes
$vec1.a
[1] 2 3 4

$vec1.b
[1] 10 11 12

$vec1.c
[1] 17 18 19 20

$vec2.a
[1]  8  9 10

$vec2.b
[1] 18 19

$vec3.a
[1] 4 5 6

$vec3.b
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
```

Therefore, for each vector in the list, I get new vectors with the indexes of the values corresponding to 1, that are "blocks" of values in-sequence. I want to programmatically verify all possible combinations of such blocks to fill a vector without overlapping the blocks. Multiple combinations are allowed.

**I've make some pictures in order to better explain my purpose:**

---

- The indexes corresponding to 1 in the example vectors:
  [image]
- Some possible combinations in order to "fill" the vectors, without overlapping:
  [image]

I am not hoping a fulfilled answer, but I do expect any point of direction I could follow in order to reach this goal. For example, I didn't know about the `rle function` until lately, and it had simplified a lot my task for catching these repeated values and their indexes. If you know any function for this, please comment below, I would be grateful for the share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult problem. Let us start by programmatically generating your vector `indexes`:

```
indexes <- list(
    vec1.a = 2:4, vec1.b = 10:12, vec1.c = 17:20,
    vec2.a = 8:10, vec2.b = 18:19,
    vec3.a = 4:6, vec3.b =11:15 )
```

By using `which` along with `diff` and `lapply`, we have the following:

```
myOnes <- do.call(c, lapply(vec_list, function(x) {
    temp <- which(x == 1)
    ind <- c(1, which(diff(temp) > 1) + 1, length(temp) + 1)
    lapply(1:(length(ind) - 1), function(y) {
        temp[ind[y]:(ind[y + 1] - 1)]
    })
}))

myOnes
$vec11
[1] 2 3 4

$vec12
[1] 10 11 12

$vec13
[1] 17 18 19 20

$vec21
[1]  8  9 10

$vec22
[1] 18 19

$vec31
[1] 4 5 6

$vec32
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
```

Now, we need to determine which vectors have no overlap with the other vectors. Since we are comparing these vectors in increasing order there is no need to recheck against an earlier vector as we will have already checked it (E.g. checking vec22 against vec13 is redundant as we will have already checked this combination when vec13 is the first vector being compared). Again, using functions from `base R` we have:

```
lenOnes <- length(myOnes)

noOverLap <- lapply(1:(lenOnes - 1), function(x) {
    which(sapply((x + 1):lenOnes, function(y) {
        length(intersect(myOnes[[x]], myOnes[[y]])) == 0
    })) + x
})

noOverLap
[[1]]            ## The first vector above i.e. vec11 only
[1] 2 3 4 5 7    ## overlaps the sixth vector i.e. vec31

[[2]]
[1] 3 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 4 6 7

[[4]]            ## The fourth vector above i.e. vec21 doesn't
[1] 5 6 7        ## overlap any vector beyond the fourth one

[[5]]
[1] 6 7

[[6]]
[1] 7
```

This looks promising and it wasn't that bad. Now we need to somehow leverage this newly created list to find all networks of non overlapping vectors. This has recursion written all over it.

```
myList <- vector("list")
n <- 0

## helper function for adding elements to our list
## ... this keeps our recursion function cleaner
addToList <- function(v) {
    if (n == 0) {
        myList[[n <<- n + 1]] <<- v
    } else if (!isTRUE(all.equal(v, myList[[n]]))) {
        myList[[n <<- n + 1]] <<- v
    }
}

recurse <- function(v, x, z) {
    if (x <= length(noOverLap)) {
        b <- intersect(z, noOverLap[[x]])
        if (length(b) > 0)
            for (i in b)
                recurse(c(v, i), i, b)
    } else {
        addToList(v)
    }
    addToList(v)
}
```

You will also note that we make use of the `<<-` (i.e. `scoping assignment`) in order to update our list.

Running our recursion function over every index of our list `noOverLap`, we obtain every combination of vectors that do not overlap:

```
for (i in seq_along(noOverLap))
    recurse(i, i, noOverLap[[i]])

head(myList)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 5

[[3]]
[1] 1 2

[[4]]
[1] 1 3 4 7

[[5]]
[1] 1 3 4

[[6]]
[1] 1 3 7

## looking at some of the middle elements
myList[21:25]    ## length(myList) is 43
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 3 4 6

[[4]]
[1] 3 4 7

[[5]]
[1] 3 4
```

The output above tells us every combination of vectors from `myOnes` that don't overlap.

Let's take a closer look at `myList[[4]]` to get an idea of what's going on:

```
myList[[4]]
[1] 1 3 4 7

myOnes[myList[[4]]]    ## the 1st, 3rd, 4th, and 7th vectors of myOnes
$vec11
[1] 2 3 4

$vec13
[1] 17 18 19 20

$vec21
[1]  8  9 10

$vec32
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
```

To prove that there is no overlap, we can concatenate these vectors, sort them, take the diff and make sure there are no zero values.

```
unlist(myOnes[myList[[4]]])
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 vec211 vec212 vec213 vec321 vec322 vec323 vec324 vec325 
     2      3      4     17     18     19     20      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15

 sort(unlist(myOnes[myList[[4]]]))
 vec111 vec112 vec113 vec211 vec212 vec213 vec321 vec322 vec323 vec324 vec325 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 
      2      3      4      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15     17     18     19     20 

 diff(sort(unlist(myOnes[myList[[4]]])))
 vec112 vec113 vec211 vec212 vec213 vec321 vec322 vec323 vec324 vec325 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 
      1      1      4      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      2      1      1      1 

 any(diff(sort(unlist(myOnes[myList[[4]]]))) == 0)
 [1] FALSE
```

And finally to get our combinations of indices, we can do the following:

```
indCombos <- lapply(myList, function(x) unlist(myOnes[x]))

head(indCombos)
[[1]]
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec121 vec122 vec123 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 
     2      3      4     10     11     12     17     18     19     20 

[[2]]
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec121 vec122 vec123 vec221 vec222 
     2      3      4     10     11     12     18     19 

[[3]]
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec121 vec122 vec123 
     2      3      4     10     11     12 

[[4]]
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 vec211 vec212 vec213 vec321 vec322 vec323 vec324 vec325 
     2      3      4     17     18     19     20      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15 

[[5]]
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 vec211 vec212 vec213 
     2      3      4     17     18     19     20      8      9     10 

[[6]]
vec111 vec112 vec113 vec131 vec132 vec133 vec134 vec321 vec322 vec323 vec324 vec325 
     2      3      4     17     18     19     20     11     12     13     14     15
```

Comment: AWESOME! In fact, it requires quite logical thoughts! All in R base functions, that's really great! I have to get used to using `diff` more often. Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva, base R can be quite powerful!! In fact I really like what a respected R user by the name of [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) says on his profile page (point 4: *"Learn base R before you learn any fancy packages such as dplyr. It is a nice package and all, but it was designed for very specific things. Many many operations could be done much more efficiently using base R"*). Anywho, this was a very fun problem... good luck.